# Regex for obtaining all key value pairs with delimiter

Tags: java, regex, scala

My input will always look something like this with an arbitrary amount of key/value pairs:

```
"irrelevant part[identifier]key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3"
```

and the desired end result is `[key1, val1, key2, val2, key3, val3]`

I'm able to match and get `key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3` via `\[identifier](.*)` but am lost on how to grab the pairs delimited by a semi-colon.

Comment: So you do not need to check for the `[identifier]` at all in the string?

Comment: I do need to check that `[identifier]` exists in the string. It has to be exactly `[identifier]`, e.g. `[identifier5]` is invalid

Comment: For your desired output, how about: [`(?<=\G\b[;=]|\[identifier])\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/NXr0FE/1) (another `\G` based pattern without distinguishing key/value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex regex are powerful but notoriously difficult to comprehend and maintain, and also can get quite slow.
You don't seem to need one for your case at all, I would go with something like this:

```
input
 .dropWhile(_ != ']')
 .tail
 .split(";")
 .map { _.split("=") }
 .collect { case Array(k,v) => k -> v }
 .toMap
```

Comment: Can `[identifier]` be exactly checked instead of dropping characters?

Comment: `input.split("""\[identifier\]""").last` ?

Comment: @stackoverflowflowflwofjlw see my answer, yes, "positive lookbehind"

Comment: Great answer! I believe `map`  yields the same result in this case as `collect`.  Would it be better ?

Comment: Where is this taking the `[identifier]` into account?

Comment: @bobblebubble in the second comment from the top :D

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip yes, map will do the same thing, unless the string is malformed: e.g., `.map` will crash if key (or value) includes a `=` (or if there is no `=` at all), while `collect` simply skips those pieces.

Comment: @Dima Does this require `[identifier]` to occur in the string?

Comment: @bobblebubble yes, but not only. It requires the string to comply with the format in OP.

Comment: I can't see how this solution would be considerably simpler to maintain than using regex. But I'm a regexer :) Imho would make sense to mention the `split` in answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble I guess, you could say that I am "a regexer" too in some ways. But I also believe in using the most fitting tool for every task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern with a `\G` operator:

```scala
val text = "irrelevant part[identifier]key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3"
val regex = """(?:\G(?!^);|\[identifier])([\w-]+)=([^;]*)""".r
val results = (regex findAllIn text).matchData.map(x => (x.group(1), x.group(2))).toMap
println(results) // => Map(key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2, key3 -> val3)
```

See [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/9IJa0c) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6HjDS/4). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^);|\[identifier])` - either the end of the previous match and then a `;` char, or `[identifier]` char sequence
- `([\w-]+)` - Group 1: one or more word or `-` chars
- `=` - a `=` char and
- `([^;]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than semi-colon.

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to achieve this same result with `\[identifier](.*)` and splitting by `;`?

Comment: @stackoverflowflowflwofjlw Yes, but I am not sure you do not have any text after the key-value pairs. Anyway, it is also handy if you need a more sophisticated regex solution, see the update.

Comment: There will never be more input after the `key=value` pairings. Is there a single regex that can grab everything after `[identifier]`, split by `;`, then split by `=`?

Comment: @stackoverflowflowflwofjlw What do you need to get in the end? What structure? Just use two capturing groups in the last regex, `val regex = """(?:\G(?!^);|\[identifier])(\w+)=([^;]*)""".r`, see [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/eJZpar).

Comment: I want a map structure, so I'm thinking I could use what you just posted and just do `collect { case Array(k,v) => k -> v }
 .toMap`

Comment: @stackoverflowflowflwofjlw Maybe `toMap` will be enough, see the code now.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called "positive lookbehind": [More technical description](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> Matches a group before the main expression ***without including it in the result.***

[From [regexr](https://regexr.com/)]

`(?<=` ... "regex" ... `)`

So `(?<=[identifier])(.*)` in your case yields `key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3`

This you can then `split` and then use another simple regex to get your `Array` of `Key`/`Value` `Tuples` or as a `Map`

```scala
val regexResult: String = "key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3"
val splitKeyValuePairs: Array[String] = result.split(";")

val keyValueRegex: Regex = """(.*)=(.*)""".r

val keyValueTupleArray: Array[(String, String)] = splitKeyValuePairs.collect{
    case keyValueRegex(k, v) => (k, v)
}

val keyValueMap: Map[String, String] = keyValueTupleArray.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `key1, val1, key2, val2, key3, val3]` as the output for the format of the given string:

```
val input = "irrelevant part[identifier]key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3"

val result = input.split("""\[identifier]""") match {
  case Array(_, t) => t.split("[=;]")
  case _ => Array.empty
}
```

Output

```
Array(key1, val1, key2, val2, key3, val3)
```

---

Another option could be using split, then use `grouped(2)` and create a Map out of the tuples:

```
val result = input.split("""\[identifier]""") match {
  case Array(_, t) =>
    t.split("[=;]")
      .grouped(2)
      .collect { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }
      .toMap
  case _ => Map.empty
}
```

Or with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/66Z1lT/1) matching the key=value pairs after te `[identifier]` until the end of the string:

```
val pattern = """\[identifier]([^\s;=]+=[^\s;=]*(?:;[^\s;=]+=[^\s;=]*)*)$""".r

val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(input) match {
  case Some(v) =>
    v.group(1)
      .split("[=;]")
      .grouped(2)
      .collect { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }
      .toMap
  case _ => Map.empty
}
```

The last 2 code examples will return

```
val result: Map[String,String] = Map(key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2, key3 -> val3)
```